# Mongoose findone não retornar os valores

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express.js, mongoose

Galera, estou com um problema aqui que não sei mais o que tentar, estou usando express + mongoose.

Minha model

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let users = mongoose.Schema({}, {strict: true});
module.exports = mongoose.model('users', users);
```

Minha controller

```
const usersModel = require('../models/users.js');

exports.token = async (req, res) => {
    let data = req.body;
    if (data.email === undefined || data.email === null) {
       return res.status(400).json({msg: 'E-mail é obrigatório'});
    }
    var user = usersModel.findOne({email: data.email});
    console.log(user);
}
```

Retorno do user

```
model {
'$__':
InternalCache {
strictMode: true,
selected: {},
shardval: undefined,
saveError: undefined,
validationError: undefined,
adhocPaths: undefined,
removing: undefined,
inserting: undefined,
version: undefined,
getters: {},
_id: 5bf1a5b535ff0f0038cea73c,
populate: undefined,
populated: undefined,
wasPopulated: false,
scope: undefined,
activePaths:
    StateMachine {
    paths: { __v: 'init', _id: 'init' },
    states:
    { ignore: {},
        default: {},
        init: { __v: true, _id: true },
        modify: {},
        require: {} },
    stateNames: [ 'require', 'modify', 'init', 'default', 'ignore' ] },
pathsToScopes: {},
ownerDocument: undefined,
fullPath: undefined,
emitter:
    EventEmitter {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
    _maxListeners: 0 },
'$options': true },
isNew: false,
errors: undefined,
_doc:
{ __v: 0,
active: true,
password: 'sha1$0ff8d815$1$1ee620b675cd6f5f78f76c116023b9b00c5d79cc',
name: 'Nicolas',
email: 'nicolas@whentoday.com.br',
_id: 5bf1a5b535ff0f0038cea73c },
'$init': true }
```

Não sei o que estou fazendo de errado, queria que retornasse apenas os valores, conseguem me ajudar?

Obrigado :)

Answer (score 1):

Na forma que você escreveu é como se estivesse associando o DocumentQuery para a variável. A forma correta de obter o resultado pode ser de duas maneiras:

1 - Como já usou o async na declaração da função, é só colocar o `await` antes do usersModel.findOne({}).

2 - Declarar uma função de callback, `usersModel.findOne({},function(erro, user) {})`.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente falta o [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).

Se você deu o async, tem que dar o await para esperar a consulta antes de exibir

Tenta assim:

```
var user = await usersModel.findOne({email: data.email});
```